How to make one User Interface Grabbable and Dragable in Unreal Game Engine 5 VR project?
In my VR project which is developed by Unreal game engine 5, I have created one widget blueprint class to show one user interface. User interface has all the required features like menu and I have hover and clickable features as well. The user interface is created with collision of two hands and it is moving with my vision.
Now, the thing I want is to make the user interface grabbable with one hand and by moving the UI, I can fix that to a specific position.
So, I need some guidance to perform this task. Any resource like tutorial or explanation with blueprint will be really appreciable.
